# Send multiple commands to subprocess, speed issue

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess, adb

I need to send multiple commands to the windows cmd through python. 
I started by using this

```
os.system("start cmd /c adb -s "+self.name+" shell input tap 350 530")
```

The problem is  if I do 10 of these  instructions it take to long.
Then I tried to use this way

```
subprocess.Popen("start cmd /c adb -s "+self.name+" shell input tap 350 530",shell=True)
```

It improve a little but not too much.

I think the problem is that it starts a new prompt everytime, what is the fastest way of send 10 of this commands to prompt without closing it?

Comment: *the problem is that it starts a new prompt everytime* - it is not the problem

Comment: that's not a speed issue? It's anyway of prevent that?